# jquery load or post issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jquery  to load external html file inside the div tags with .load() function but it doesn't work. It doesn't get loaded. Here is the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/h9sngz95/

What I'm doing wrong? I get error {"error": "Please use POST request"}
but no matter of I use .post or .load still the same result. The content is not shown. What is wrong? Please help.

```
<body> 
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logolanhai.jpg"    
alt="" /></a></div>
 <ul>
<li><a href="" onclick="about();"><span>关于我们</span></a></li>
<li><a href="" onclick="services();"><span>服务项目</span></a></li>
<li><a href="" onclick="references();"><span>成功案例</span></a></li>
<li><a href="" onclick="contact();"><span>联系我们</span></a></li>
</ul>    
 </div>


<div id="bodyinsert"></div>
</body>

function about()
{
$.post( "about.html", function( data ) { $( "bodyinsert" ).html( data );
});

//   $("#bodyinsert").load("about.html");
}

function services()
{


   $("#bodyinsert").load("services.html");

}

function references()
{


   $("#bodyinsert").load("references.html");

}

function contact()
{


   $("#bodyinsert").load("contact.html");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Neither JSFiddle nor StackSnippets will allow AJAX as far as I understand (except to specific jsfiddle pages) Also look in the console for errors
2. Post to get an HTML page is not likely what you want.
3. `$("#bodyinsert").load("about.html");` is likely what you want - it does mean the page has to come from a the same server, same origin as your script - you cannot use AJAX in Chrome to file system.

Also do yourself a favour and use href or data-attributes for the urls and preventDefault on the click

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nav").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop link
    $("#bodyinsert").load(this.href);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logolanhai.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="selected"><a href="index.html" class="nav"><span>主页</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html" class="nav"><span>关于我们</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html" class="nav"><span>服务项目</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="references.html" class="nav"><span>成功案例</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" class="nav"><span>联系我们</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div id="bodyinsert"></div>
```